# Is revealing just the AUTH_KEY a security issue?

Tags: plugins, urls, security

I am troubleshooting a Wordpress plugin issue. It is a plugin that generates a zip file of existing files on the server and returns a link to download the file.

The plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sp-client-document-manager/

The plugin add-on that is the source of the issue.

http://smartypantsplugins.com/downloads/sp-client-document-manager-batch-operations/

The plugin creates a directory to save the generated zip file using the AUTH_KEY as the name of the directory. When the url is returned to the client it contains the AUTH_KEY as part of its path.

```
$zip_path        = '' . SP_CDM_UPLOADS_DIR_URL . '' . AUTH_KEY. '/'
```

This returns a url similar to the following:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/sp-client-document-manager/{the_wordpress_auth_key}/0123456789.zip
```

If any of the characters in the AUTH_KEY are not allowed in a url the download will return a 404. This is happening but that can easily be fixed by changing the AUTH_KEY to a string that will work in a url. My worry is the fact that it contains the AUTH_KEY.

Is revealing the AUTH_KEY by itself a reason for concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `AUTH_KEY` and it´s brothers where introduced in WordPress 2.6 to improve safety for logged in users. They are used to encrypt and validate the information in your backend login cookie.

While revealing the `AUTH_KEY` alone might not be a real security issue, you should nevertheless not output/use this anywhere to give less surface for attacks.

Furthermore I don´t see why you would use the `AUTH_KEY` to prepare a folder/download link. I think it would be much better to use something like [`time()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.time.php) to generate folder names if you want randomness or uniqueness or whatever without compromising the security of the system.

**Update:** I opened [a thread in the plugins support area.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-security-concern-in-this-plugin?replies=1#post-8017393) Let´s see if the author responds to it.

Comment: revealing any of the generated keys **is** a major security issue.

Comment: ...not to mention just bad plugin design. Should be using random, alhpanumeric strings that relate to nothing else i.e. `random_bytes` (which WP even polyfills for PHP5 installs)

Comment: Oh, never heard about `random_bytes`, looks useful.